# Problema con Decodificador JSON [Python]

Tags: python

tengo que hacer un programa mediante tkinter que muestre los datos de las provincias. Los datos están almacenados en un archivo .json y deben ser leidos mediante un decodificador. Estuve intentando varias cosas y guiandome en los apuntes que me han dado pero no le hayo solución a lo que está mal. El error que me muestra consola es el siguiente

**File "C:\Users\lucia\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value**

El codigo del decodificador es el siguiente

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
from modulo_ManejadorProvincias import ManejadorProvincias
from modulo_provincia import Provincia

class ObjectEncoder(object):
    __pathArchivo=None
 
    def __init__(self, pathArchivo):
        self.__pathArchivo= pathArchivo
     
    def decodificarDiccionario(self, d):
        if '__class__' not in d:
            return d
        else:
            class_name=d['__class__']
            class_= eval(class_name)
            if class_name=='ManejadorProvincias':
                provincias= d['Provincia']
                manejador= class_()
                for i in range (len(provincias)):
                    dProvincia= provincias[i]
                    class_name= dProvincia.pop('__class__')
                    class_= eval(class_name)
                    atributos= dProvincia['__atributos__']
                    unaProvincia= class_(**atributos)
                    manejador.agregarProvincia(unaProvincia)
            return manejador
     
    def guardarJSONArchivo (self, diccionario):
        with Path(self.__pathArchivo).open("w", encoding="UTF-8") as destino:
            json.dump(diccionario, destino, indent=4)
            destino.close()
    
    def leerJSONArchivo(self):
        with Path(self.__pathArchivo).open(encoding="UTF-8") as fuente:
            diccionario=json.load(fuente)
            fuente.close()
            return diccionario
```

Y el archivo JSON es el siguiente. Lo agrego tambien por las dudas que sea un error porque este mal genereado el archivo, aunque yo no le veo problema.

```
{
    "__class__": "ManejadorProvincias",
    "Provincia": [
        {
        "__class__": "Provincia",
        "__atributos__": {
            "nombre": 'San Juan',
            "capital": 'San Juan',
            "cantidad_hab": 900000
            "cantidad_dep": 19
            }
        },

        {
        "__class__": "Provincia",
        "__atributos__": {
            "nombre": 'Mendoza',
            "capital": 'Mendoza',
            "cantidad_hab": 1200000,
            "cantidad_dep": 16
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ¿Falta una coma después de "cantidad_hab": 900000?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder! Acabo de corregir ese error, no lo habia visto. Aun así, sigue tirandome el mismo error que antes :(

Comment: El JSON que muestras no es válido. Aparte de la coma que faltaba, dentro de un JSON las cadenas han de ir delimitadas por comillas dobles y no simples (como es el caso de `'San Juan'` o `'Mendoza'`)

Comment: Prueba a abrir tu archivo JSON directamente con tu browser. A mi me arroja errores: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 7 column 23 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente sería mi consejo:

```
def guardarJSONArchivo (self, diccionario):
    with Path(self.__pathArchivo).open("w", encoding="UTF-8") as destino:
        json.dumps(diccionario, destino)

def leerJSONArchivo(self):
    with Path(self.__pathArchivo).open(encoding="UTF-8") as fuente:
        diccionario=json.loads(fuente.readline())
        return diccionario
```

Al usar `whith` el documento que abres se cierra automáticamente una vez terminas de trabajar con él, por eso he eliminado `variable.close()` ya que es algo innecesario.
También he eliminado el `ident=4` para que el contenido esté solo en la 1ra línea, de esta forma al usar `leerJSONArchivo()` tendrás en la variable `diccionario` un dic totalmente accesible.